# Add images dynamically based on random number

Tags: python

I work on a simple mathematics learning programs for my 4 year old daughter with the help of images.
Based on a random number that we can call X, a for loop will run X number of times and print an image X number of times. The image will be selected from the list by a random number also that we can call Y.

If X is 2 the image Y will be printed to the screen 2 times using for loop.

The problem is I do not know how to do. :P
If anyone can help me with this I would be grateful! I'm using python 3.2 and Tkinter.

Here is example code for my image list.

```
    self.imageListRegular = []
    self.imageListRegular.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="Bilder/Bird-icon.png"))
    self.imageListRegular.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="Bilder/elephant-icon.png"))      
    self.imageListRegular.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="Bilder/fish-icon.png"))
    self.imageListRegular.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="Bilder/ladybird-icon.png"))
    self.imageListRegular.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="Bilder/zebra-icon.png"))
```

Sincerely, Robert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the python `random` module

```
import random
image = random.choice(self.imageListRegular) #this is your 'Y' variable
times = random.randint(1, 4) #this is your 'X' variable
```

Then do you for loop, which I imagine looks something like this (I don't have Tkinter, so I can't test the code. This is derived from a sample [here](http://www.wadsworth.org/spider_doc/spider/docs/python/spipylib/tkinter.html)):

```
import Tkinter 
root = Tkinter.Tk() 
for i in xrange(times):
    Tkinter.Label(root, image=image).pack() 
root.mainloop() # Start the GUI
```

`random.choice` returns a random element in a given sequence, so `random.choice(["apples", "bananas", "oranges"])` would return either "apples", "bananas", or "oranges"

`random.randint(low, high)` will return a random integer between low and high, including low and high. So if you wanted to display the image between 1 and 4 times, `random.randint(1, 4)` would do the trick.

Comment: One thing I would add is that if you don't want to allow repeats, `random.sample` works.